# Using Webkit rendering for java based Desktop applications

Tags: java, user-interface, webkit, embedded-browser

Is it possible to use Webkit for rendering on a desktop application? I have looked at CEF but it's not for Java. Is there any toolkit available in java for this?

Comment: Interested to know this as well. Would be great to use the flexibility and standardization of html5 for interface pieces on desktop applications, while not being buttonholed into a web environment.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, check out JavaFX's HTML rendering. It uses WebKit.

http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm

Answer (score 0):

There is [Java CEF wrapper for Java](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef)

[Related post about setting it up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192279/how-to-integrate-chromium-embedded-framework-cef-with-java)

[Support forum](http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewforum.php?f=17)