# Setting up CEF development in Eclipse for Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, chromium, chromium-embedded

I m new to this framework. I m facing problem in setting up development environment for CEF in eclipse. I want to embed chromium in Java application. I have searched a lot, but there is no proper tutorial or steps which shows how to do it. Can anyone please guide me through this? or at-least provide me with reliable guide, docs. on how to? I m not able to setup/build using eclipse.

Comment: In Eclipse, create a maven project and follow these steps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192279/how-to-integrate-chromium-embedded-framework-cef-with-java/24951323?noredirect=1#comment40297660_24951323

Comment: I dont want to use maven, is there any way to use only java?

Comment: Yes. In step 3, you should add all libraries {gluegen-rt.jar, gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar, jogl-all.jar, jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar, jcef.jar} to your project. Skip step 4

Comment: Does this work? If not, inform me please, i will try creating a project in my Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple Java application build. Follow these steps and add jar as external references. 
[How to integrate Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192279/how-to-integrate-chromium-embedded-framework-cef-with-java/24951323?noredirect=1#comment40297660_24951323)