# CEF development in Eclipse with Java

Tags: java, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to develop a browser for a Java application and I found [JCEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef). I made this [guide](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding) without any error . Now I want to try the simple example "MainFrame.Java", which was also build. 
I created a project in eclipse, added the jar-files to library and copied the MainFrame-file.

If I run it, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jcef in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at org.cef.CefApp.<init>(CefApp.java:157)
at org.cef.CefApp.getInstance(CefApp.java:246)
at org.cef.CefApp.getInstance(CefApp.java:233)
at test.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:71)
at test.MainFrame.main(MainFrame.java:154)
```

I also tried the steps described in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761607/setting-up-cef-development-in-eclipse-for-java) and the link in the comment. But if I download the file in the first [step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24951323/7140445) I don't have the described files or paths.

Does someone have an idea how I could make it run or am I doing it completely wrong ?

Code of the MainFrame file:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5570653778104813836L;
private final JTextField address_;
private final CefApp cefApp_;
private final CefClient client_;
private final CefBrowser browser_;
private final Component browerUI_;

/**
 * To display a simple browser window, it suffices completely to create an
 * instance of the class CefBrowser and to assign its UI component to your
 * application (e.g. to your content pane). But to be more verbose, this
 * CTOR keeps an instance of each object on the way to the browser UI.
 */
private MainFrame(String startURL, boolean useOSR, boolean isTransparent) {

    CefApp.addAppHandler(new CefAppHandlerAdapter(null) {
        @Override
        public void stateHasChanged(org.cef.CefApp.CefAppState state) {
            // Shutdown the app if the native CEF part is terminated
            if (state == CefAppState.TERMINATED)
                System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
    settings.windowless_rendering_enabled = useOSR;
    cefApp_ = CefApp.getInstance(settings);

    client_ = cefApp_.createClient();

    browser_ = client_.createBrowser(startURL, useOSR, isTransparent);
    browerUI_ = browser_.getUIComponent();

    address_ = new JTextField(startURL, 100);
    address_.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            browser_.loadURL(address_.getText());
        }
    });

    getContentPane().add(address_, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    getContentPane().add(browerUI_, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pack();
    setSize(800, 600);
    setVisible(true);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            CefApp.getInstance().dispose();
            dispose();
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MainFrame("http://www.google.com", OS.isLinux(), false);
}
```

}

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Please provide the code that you are running in order to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. My problem was that I build the binary files not correctly