# How can i create Java project using Java Chromium Embedded Framework in MAC OS X?

Tags: java, macos, jar, chromium-embedded

I want to create java application on Netbeans by using JCEF.

1. gluegen-rt.jar & gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar & jcef.jar & jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal.jar & jogl-all.jar files imported to project
2. From VM option, libcef.dylib & libjcef.dylib dynamic libraries added to library path
3. Chromium Embedded Framework.framework placed to Frameworks directory

   however when i run the project, "resource_bundle.cc(280)] locale_file_path.empty()" error occur.After some research i found that "Chromium Embedded Framework.framework->Resources->en.lproj->locale.pak" file  not found or integrated to project improper way.

Some [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192279/how-to-integrate-chromium-embedded-framework-cef-with-java#answer-24951323) exist but i cannot implement in MAC OS X?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I've found this as a pending issue on JCEF that they said it won't be fixed.

To make it work, you need to setup the running environment as an OS X app bundle. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Inside your project folder, create a new bundle folder. For example: A folder called "test.app" - the app extension identifies the folder as an app bundle.
2. Right click on it and click on "Show Package Contents"
3. Copy the JCEF libraries and Resources using exactly the same structure as on the "jcef_app" that comes with the JCEF binary for Mac. To see inside it, do the same "Show Package Contents". The structure has a main folder called "Contents" with all the resources and framework folder inside.
4. Setup your IDE (I did this on Eclipse) to run your application having the working directory as you "test.app".
5. Remember to setup your VM options to find the libraries on the new path inside the "test.app"

For me that was it. It finally ran normally.