# Embed Chrome in a SWT application in java

Tags: java, swt, chromium

I want to embed chrome inside a SWT application. I was trying with [JCEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef). But not able to succeed.

I came across the following link: [How to integrate Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192279/how-to-integrate-chromium-embedded-framework-cef-with-java)
But I don't want to use maven as mentioned in step3.

I need a step by step details of how to embed a chrome.

Comment: "I was trying with JCEF. But not able to succeed." - what wasn't working? Sounds like you were on the right track by using JCEF, so do you have a specific question about an error or some problem you ran into?

Comment: As mentioned in [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192279/how-to-integrate-chromium-embedded-framework-cef-with-java Step 3 says to install some jar files in local repository. I have 2 doubts in this  1) I dont want to use maven  2) jcef.jar is not available in the downloded directory

Answer (score 1):

If you can't build JCEF you can use some maven builds and forks like:

- [GitHub: Pandomium](https://github.com/Panda-Programming-Language/Pandomium) - fork with maven builds and natvies
- [Maven: JavaCef](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bitbucket.johness/java-cef) - clean maven builds

> ~ *I dont want to use maven*

Maven just hosts jar files so you can download it and add to your project manually but it's not recommended at all.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using SWT, I think that you should checkout this: [Browser implement Chromium support](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=405031)

This request lead to this project: [Chromium for SWT](https://github.com/maketechnology/chromium.swt)

Currently is working on version 59 of chormium and uses the SWT Browser API.