# Eclipse - library set in both classpath and command line argument but application crashes

Tags: java, eclipse, java-11, chromium-embedded, openjfx

I've added [this](https://github.com/jcefbuild/jcefbuild/releases) JCEF library to my JFX application following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192279/how-to-integrate-chromium-embedded-framework-cef-with-java/24951323?noredirect=1#comment40297660_24951323),
first: under run configuration -> arguments -> vm arguments as

```
--module-path "D:\Strumenti_di_sviluppo\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib" --add-modules=javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.web,javafx.swing
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=resources/pj/login/login.config -cp "D:\ECLIPSE_WORKSPACES\JavaFX-workspace\pj\lib\java-cef-build-bin\bin;D:\ECLIPSE_WORKSPACES\JavaFX-workspace\pj\lib\java-cef-build-bin\bin\*" -Djava.library.path=D:\ECLIPSE_WORKSPACES\JavaFX-workspace\pj\lib\java-cef-build-bin\bin\lib\win64
```

and also on project -> build path -> configure build path -> libraries
then I added them with "add jar".

Eclipse is well capable to solve the names (I have no warnings about objects not found) but as I run the application the class-loader dies when it looks for `org.cef.handler.CefDisplayHandler`.

Anyway if I run the "run.bat" the sample runs. Hence I think it should be an issue in Eclipse but I have no ideas about where to look.

Note: other parts of the application running on jfx are fine, only this component faiuls to load.

Comment: Configure the modules, modulepath, classpath in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_. Setting it also via VM arguments in the launch configuration conflicts with the project settings (hit the _Show Command Line_ button in the launch configuration to see the result).